# How can I read the body and download the attached file/s from Gmail with Python2.7?

Tags: python, gmail, attachment, content-type, mixed

I'm trying to read the body of my inbox folder on my Email and, if there is an attachment, download it. I've reached to read the body of the received mails, but only if there isn't any attachment on it.

Now I've reached to read all body messages of the received mails, but I can't download the attached files inside the mail yet.

Next, You'll see my code, if it can help someone, you're free to use it.

```
import imaplib
import email
import myEmails
from myEmails import dicCorreos,dicContras

class Attachement(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None;
        self.content_type = None;
        self.size = None;
        self.name = None;

def parse_attachment(message_part):
    content_disposition = message_part.get("Content-Disposition", None)
    if content_disposition:
        dispositions = content_disposition.strip().split(";")
        if content_disposition and dispositions[0].lower() == "attachment":
            attachment = Attachement()
            attachment.data = message_part.get_payload(decode=True)
            attachment.content_type = message_part.get_content_type()
            attachment.size = len(attachment.data)
            attachment.name = message_part.get_filename()
            return attachment
    return None

def get_text(self, email_message_instance):
    maintype = email_message_instance.get_content_maintype()
    if maintype == 'multipart':
        for part in email_message_instance.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                return part.get_payload()
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                for part2 in part.get_payload():
                    return part2.get_payload()
    elif maintype == 'text':
        return email_message_instance.get_payload()

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(dicCorreos['correo3'],dicContras['contra3'])
mail.list()
mail.select("inbox")

result,data = mail.search(None,"ALL")
# result=OK,data=['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...']
if result=='OK':
    latest_id = data[0].split()[-6:]

list_data=[]
for i in range(len(latest_id)):
list_data.append(email.message_from_string(mail.fetch(latest_id[int(i)],"(RFC822)")[1][0][1]))

print len(list_data)
print range(len(list_data))
for i in range(len(list_data)):
    correoDeOrigen=email.utils.parseaddr(list_data[i]['From'])[1]
    #if correoDeOrigen!=dicCorreos['correo1']:
    #print "No era lo esperado\n",correoDeOrigen,dicCorreos['correo1']         
    #pass
    #and email_message_list[i]['Subject']=='Voy a probar'
    print correoDeOrigen
    print list_data[i].items()[-1]
    mensaje = get_text('',list_data[i])
    print 'Titulo: ',list_data[i]['Subject']
    if mensaje==None:
        print 'mensaje none en posicion i = ',i
        print '\n Guardo el archivo adjunto \n'
        att=parse_attachment(list_data[i])
        print 'Llega aqui?'
        if att != None:
            print 'entra en el if del archivo'
            print "I'm  into the if"
            file = open(att.name, 'w')
            file.write(att.data)
            file.close()
            print '\n comprobar si se ha guardado \n'
            print 'Have I saved the file?'
        else:
            print 'No, no puedo guardar nada, tengo problemas'
            print "No, I can't save nothing, I have a problem here"
    else:
        print 'Mensaje:\n',mensaje
    print '\n-------------------------FIN DE ITERACIÓN Nº', i,'----------------------------------------'
```

I have some problems with the type of message of some of them. The type of message without attachments are 'Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative; and I have successfully the body of the email. But if the type of message with attachment is 'Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; I can't download the attached files. Now my error message doesn't work, I'll look for a new form to fix it

Please, could someone help me in this challenge?

I know the email type is organiced perfectly, but I can't understand it. If someone could help me to understand it...

Thanks

Here, the results of the execution

```
('Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative; boundary="001a..."')
Titulo:  hola
Mensaje:
hola

-------------------------FIN DE ITERACIÓN Nº 0 ----------------------
('Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative;     
boundary="f4f5..."')
Titulo:  hola
Mensaje:
que tal


-------------------------FIN DE ITERACIÓN Nº 1 ----------------------
('Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative; boundary="001a..."')
Titulo:  que tal
Mensaje:
que tal



-------------------------FIN DE ITERACIÓN Nº 2 -----------------------
('Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative; boundary="f403..."')
Titulo:  que tal
Mensaje:
hola


-------------------------FIN DE ITERACIÓN Nº 3 -----------------------
('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; 
boundary="001a..."')
Titulo:  Voy a probar
mensaje none en posicion i =  4

Guardo el archivo adjunto 

Llega aqui?
No, no puedo guardar nada, tengo problemas
No, I can't save nothing, I have a problem here

----------------FIN DE ITERACIÓN Nº 4 ---------------------------
('Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative;     
boundary="001a..."')
Titulo:  Voy a probar
Mensaje:
A no enviar
un archivo adjunto
vete a saber si
es por eso que
cambia el content-type
de multipart/alternative
a multipart/mixed


-------------------------FIN DE ITERACIÓN Nº 5 ---------------------
```

Comment: Here, the results of the execution

Comment: The attachment is a pdf file, but I wish download png, jpg, xml, xlsx, csv, json, py... some of the most common types of files...